# Cache-Control not being picked up by performance analysis tools for my website (Amazon CF/S3)

Tags: performance, cache, cache-control, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So, I have this website that is hosted in Amazon S3/CF and when I run any Performance analysis tool I get the following recommendation to set browser caching in some files:
[image: Leverage Browser Caching]

So, I set in (most of the files) the: --cache-control "max-age=7776000, public" meta-tag as you can see here for example in animate.css:

`curl -I https://counsellor.life/assets/css/animate.css
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 71569    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 71569
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 22:28:53 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=7776000, public
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 May 2017 02:07:53 GMT
ETag: "8bab56c3164c346a680ad414e6f1d7aa"
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 56908f89e8d17ba579c0607313114955.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)`

CloudFront Configuration under Behavior:

[image: CloudFront Caching Config]

However I still getting the suggestion in those tools. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Do a CloudFront invalidation for all objects `*`.  Wait for it to complete, and run the test again.

Comment: technically you have added an HTTP header, not a meta tag.   Images can't have meta tags.

Comment: I did the invalidation already, issue persists.

Comment: Did the tools ever pick up on your cache control, or are they still reporting problems?   I usually use `Expires` headers, so it is possible that the `max-age` isn't recognized.   However, it does appear to be valid and should take precedence over `Expires`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549177/expires-vs-max-age-which-one-takes-priority-if-both-are-declared-in-a-http-resp/7549558#7549558

Comment: @StephenOstermiller after some DAYS and at least 5 more invalidations it worked. I didn't investigate properly, so I have no clue why it happened. Its working now.

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate that it is working now.  An answer is no longer needed.